# Node.js: Google Analytics in the server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-analytics

Can I submit Google Analytics event in Node.js/Express?
Is there any SDK for that?

I'd like to do something similar to: [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're probably looking for [universal-analytics](https://github.com/peaksandpies/universal-analytics) which allows you to send [Events](https://github.com/peaksandpies/universal-analytics) much like `ga` on the browser like so:

```
visitor.event("Event Category", "Event Action").send()
```

where `visitor` is instantiated like so:

```
var visitor = ua('UA-XXXX-XX') // Your Google Analytics ID
```

Comment: Can I use the same `UA-XXXX-XX` I am using with Google Analytics?

Comment: @Valeri Yes you can

Comment: I'd suggest you to learn carefully the description of measurement protocol (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) and description of Google Analytics user identification (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id) to be sure that you're sending relevant event's data to GA

Comment: upvoted! if the user is logged in you can take in a userId (not email) to identify the user. what do you do when the user is NOT logged in to identify the user

Comment: @PirateApp you use the cid: 555 which means anonymous user in GA world. See this url on step 5 under sample application: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/integrating-with-analytics?tab=node.js#sample_application